# How does android communicate with dynamic services?

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to develop an app and I want it to bring in data from a `mySQL` database. But from some reading I have done on different sites, I am realizing that it is probably not going to happen. But I am curious to know, how do apps like PhoneFlix and others view that dynamic data on the application? Does it somehow just bring it in through http? If so, how would I go about doing that?  Does anyone know of any good sites that will point me in the right direction? Thanks

ezekielweb

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, android provides sqlite, not mysql. :)

You can create a thread that does whatever you want it to and it can communicate with the front activity with Bundle when you implement Handler in your activity.

such as below...

```
private void do_what_i_want() {

  new Thread() {

   public void run() {

     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("whatyouwant", value);

     Message m = new Message();
     m.setData(bundle);
     handler.sendMessage(msg);
   }

 }.start

}


private Handler handler = new Handler() {

 @Override

 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

   super.handleMessage(msg);

   Bundle b = msg.getData();

   String whatyouwant = b.getString("whatyouwant");

   ["you can refresh your view here"]

 }

}
```

hope I'm on the right track... :p

Comment: But will that communicate an already existing web site sql database?  I want to have the same information available through the device and through a desktop web browser.  Is that possible. Thanks for the response.

Comment: with the proper implementation.. sure! :)

Comment: @ezekielweb: Honestly you are asking people to start making funny comments. You did not do sufficient research :).  But that does not mean that people cannot help.  Look, as with any browser based application you can expose the data from the database in a number of ways. You can use web services, etc....  So check out for starters: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database